# I want to sort the subarrays in a NumPy array that I have according to their length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I want to sort the sub-arrays in a NumPy array that I have according to their length.

For example my array is

```
myArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
           [8,9,10,11],
           [12],
           [13],
           [14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]]
```

and I want to sort them as

```
myArray = [[14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
           [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
           [8,9,10,11],
           [12],
           [13]]
```

Is there any possible way to doing this?

**The content of my sub-arrays should not change.**

Comment: `sorted(myArray, key=len, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a simple list of lists - to do what you need:

```
sorted(myArray, key=lambda x: -len(x))
```

**FOLLOW UP**: if you have a `numpy` array, as follows:

```
myArray = np.array([np.array(x) for x in [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]])
```

You can obtain a similar result:

```
np.array([y for x,y in sorted([(-len(x), x) for x in myArray])])
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([array([14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]),
   array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11]), array([12]),
   array([13])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: don't use `lambda`, just do `sorted(myArray, key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: Sorry but my sub-arrays are numpy arrays. Is there any alternative solution for NumPy.